# Java8 instantiate a Predicate

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-programming

I am new in Java8, and I want to create a Predicate that checks if a value is contained inside a List of values, so I created:

```
public class Predicates {

    public static Predicate<String> isStringValueAllowed(List<String> allowedValues) {
        return allowedValues::contains;
    }
}
```

and

```
String valueToCheck = "test";

        Predicate<String> predicate1 = (valueToCheck) -> Predicates.isStringValueAllowed(list);
```

Comment: what is `list` in `Predicates.isStringValueAllowed(list)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the `Predicate` incorrectly.

To apply it to a `String`, you should call the `Predicate`'s `test()` method, which returns a `boolean`:

```
boolean found = Predicates.isStringValueAllowed(list).test(valueToCheck);
```